# any reasons for inconsistent numpy arguments of numpy.zeros and numpy.random.randn

Tags: numpy

I'm implementing a computation using numpy zeros and numpy.random.randn

```
W1 = np.random.randn(n_h, n_x) * .01
b1 = np.zeros((n_h, 1))
```

I'm not sure why ***random.randn()*** can accept two integers while ***zeros()*** needs a tuple. Is there a good reason for that?

Cheers, JChen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most likely it's just a matter of history.  `numpy` results from the merger of several prior packages, and has a long development.  Some quirks get cleaned up, others left as is.

```
randn(d0, d1, ..., dn)
zeros(shape, dtype=float, order='C')
```

`randn` has this note:

> This is a convenience function.  If you want an interface that takes a
>   tuple as the first argument, use `numpy.random.standard_normal` instead.

```
standard_normal(size=None)
```

With `*` it is easy to pass a tuple to `randn`:

```
np.random.randn(*(1,2,3))
```

`np.zeros` takes a couple of keyword arguments. `randn` does not.  You can define a Python function with a `(*args, **kwargs)` signature.  But accepting a tuple, especially one with a common usage as `shape`, fits better.  But that's a matter of opinion.

`np.random.rand` and `np.random.random_sample` are another such pair.  Most likely `rand` and `randn` are the older versions, and `standard_normal` and `random_sample` are newer ones designed to conform to the more common `tuple` style.